# Trying to attach a texture to a quads with SOIL but nothing shows up

Tags: textures, texture-mapping, soil

Im just trying to attach a texture to a square drawn with quads using SOIL library, but nothing comes out, only the black screen. Do you have any idea why this happens?
I have binded the variable and also defined the texture coordinates according with the square itself...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>

GLuint texture[1];

int LoadGLTextures()
{
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
        "img_test.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
    );

    if(texture[0] == 0)
        return false;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    return true;
}


void init()
{

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.25f); glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.25f); glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.75f); glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.75f); glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
    LoadGLTextures();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,   0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION),
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);*/
    gluPerspective(30.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
/* Program entry point */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```